# Camera intent returns thumbnail, but want to tap on thumbnail to display original image

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I have been struggling with this now for a few days.  In my app the user taps on the point on the map (google Map v2) and then the user can take a picture and return a thumbnail to that point.  All works, but want to now tap on the thumbnail and return the original image full screen or in an imageview.  Could anyone please help me with this?

This is my camera intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_THUMBNAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

OnActivityResult:

```
 File imageStorageFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Folder");
        if (!imageStorageFolder.exists())
        {
            imageStorageFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG , "Folder created at: "+imageStorageFolder.toString());
        }
        if (data != null)
        {
            String filename = "image";
            String fileNameExtension = ".jpg";
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String imageStorageFolder1 = File.separator+"Folder"+File.separator;
            File destinationFile = new File(sdCard, imageStorageFolder1 + filename + fileNameExtension);
            Log.d(TAG, "the destination for image file is: " + destinationFile );
            if (data.getExtras() != null)
            {
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "ERROR:" + e.toString());
                }
```

then on onMarkerClick:

```
@Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker arg0){
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("bitmap" + "data");
         intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
         startActivity(intent);
          return false;
```

When tapping on the onMarkerClick a window pops up with an icon saying that this image can't be displayed. (like and image broken)

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onMarkerClick` method you create Uri this way `Uri.parse("bitmap" + "data")`. So in the end you're trying to show picture with Uri `bitmapdata`. You should pass correct Uri of the picture to `Uri.parse` method. You're saving your picture under `destinationFile` so make a `File destinationFile` a class member field and get Uri through `Uri.parse(destinationFile.toString())`.

If you want to display each picture for a given `Marker` correctly then you have to store `Uri`s of all files to which you've saved pictures. For example you can have a `Map<Integer, Uri>` in which keys will be `Marker`s ids and values will be pictures `Uri`s. Then in `onMarkerClick` get the id of clicked marker through `Marker.getId()` and use it to get appropriate `Uri` for picture from `Map`.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to show me what i need to do?

Comment: Okay, i have `Uri destinationFile;`  then added the code you gave me but app crashes now when tapping on thumbnail?  I am probably being really stupid here now..

Comment: Nevermind,  was just being a bit stupid for a second there.  Got it working now,  however it doesn't display the first image taken by the camera on the first marker,  it seems to only display the last image taken, so when i have multiple markers all of them will display the same image, which is not really what i want.

Comment: You have to store Uris of all files to which you've saved pictures. For example you can have a `Map<Integer, Uri>` in which keys will be `Marker` ids and values will be pictures Uris. Then in `onMarkerClick` get the id of clicked marker through `Marker.getId()` and use it to get appropriate Uri for picture from `Map`.

Comment: Cool Thank you so much!!, Have you got an example of that?  the reason i am asking is because i am busy training myself and find it easier to have the code and study it while i am writing my app.

Comment: No, sorry I don't have any example at hand. However I think it shouldn't cause you much trouble. Happy coding ;-)